# Lag Function to skip over previous record where there is a null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a previous value using the lag function, however it only works for data that is populated on the previous record. What I am looking to do is skip the previous record only if there is a null and look at the previous record prior to that which is not a null

```
Select LAG(previous_reference_no)OVER(ORDER BY createdon) FROM TableA
```

So say if I am at record 5,record 4 is null however record 3 is not null. So from record 5 I would want to display the value of record 4.

Hope this makes sense, please help/

Comment: Sample code and desired output would help greatly. A record isn't NULL, only a column in a row can be NULL. Which column contains NULL that you are struggling with here?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `PARTITION BY` clause?

```
Select LAG(previous_reference_no) OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN previous_reference_no IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                                        ORDER BY createdon)
FROM TableA
```

Comment: . . This doesn't work when the current value is `NULL`.

Comment: This was a bit of a stab in the dark, to be fair, @GordonLinoff , as we have no sample data/expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Standard SQL has the syntax for this:

```
SELECT LAG(previous_reference_no IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY createdon)
FROM TableA
```

Unfortunately SQL Server does not support this.  One method uses two levels of window functions and some logic:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN previous_reference_no IS NULL
             THEN MAX(prev_reference_no) OVER (PARTITION BY grp)
             ELSE LAG(previous_reference_no) OVER (PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN previous_reference_no IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                                                   ORDER BY createdon)
        END)
FROM (SELECT a.*,
             COUNT(prev_reference_no) OVER (ORDER BY a.createdon) as grp
      FROM TableA a
     ) a;
```

The logic is:

- Create a grouping that has a given reference number and all following `NULL` values in one group.
- If the reference number is `NULL`, then get the first value for the start of the group.  This would be the previous non-`NULL` value.
- If the reference number is not `NULL` then use `partition by` to look at the last not-`NULL` value.

Another method -- which is likely to be much slower -- uses `APPLY`:

```
select a.*, aprev.prev_reference_no
from TableA a outer apply
     (select top (1) aprev.*
      from TableA aprev
      where aprev.createdon < a.createdon and
            aprev.prev_reference_no is not null
     ) aprev;
```

For a small table, the performance hit might be worth the simplicity of the code.

Comment: I think you meant to remove `IGNORE NULLS` from `LAG(previous_reference_no IGNORE NULLS)` in the SQL Server solution, as you point out yourself that `IGNORE NULLS` is valid syntax for T-SQL.